# Amazon Europe Web Services - Invalid Ids Presented

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to Amazon Web Services Europe. I have opened an account with Amazon for Europe and I obtained and AWSAccessKeyId and an AWSSecretKey for Amazon Europe. My customer has sent over their Amazon Europe credentials. Is something wrong with my request?

Request

```
POST https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: CloudCartConnector/1 (Language=C#; CLI=4.0.30319.18444;  Platform=Win32NT/6.1.7601.65536; MWSClientVersion=2014-09-30)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: mws-eu.amazonservices.com
Content-Length: 359
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

AWSAccessKeyId=XX&Action=ListOrders&LastUpdatedAfter=2015-03-31T20%3A31%3A38Z&LastUpdatedBefore=2015-03- 31T20%3A31%3A52Z&MarketplaceId.Id.1=XX&SellerId=XX&Signature=XX&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2015-03-31T20%3A36%3A52Z&Version=2013-09-01
```

Response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
 <Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
<Message>Invalid ids presented</Message>
 </Error>
 <RequestId>7f89f886-b946-43d6-8bf5-bda9d03df186</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: Same problem here. Very little information about it online.

Comment: Hi, when you register for an account, you'll get a developer ID with a *. Remove the star at the end of the developer ID, when your customer gives your account permissions. See this image: http://www.jmawebtechnologies.com/getmedia/40106b91-622d-4890-a85a-6b87ab6af9f2/amazonwebservices.aspx?width=350&height=247

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and at last I found out, because there was a "space" after the merchant id or marketplace id, remove all spaces before or after the id, everything works well :)